# Interpolate many curves in parallel in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

Let's say I have an N row by M column NumPy array. Each row contains the values of each of N functions, over M intervals. I have a vector X, which contains the x-values at which the functions were evaluated. I also have another NumPy array which is a 1D vector of length N. I want to interpolate each of the N functions to find their respective values at each of the N points in the vector. For instance, if I have

```
X = np.array([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8])
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                   [2,4,6,8],
                   [1,3,5,7]]) # N = 3, M = 4
vector = np.array([0.3, 0.6, 0.5])

def f(X, matrix, vector):
   # Some code
   return interpolated_values
```

`interpolated_values` should contain `[1.5, 6, 4]` because those are the values that each row of `matrix` has when linearly interpolated at the corresponding value of `X`.

I know I could do this using loops. But, if N is very large this would be slow. What should be in the function `f` to do this interpolation in parallel?

I guess the real issue comes in if X is is not the same vector for each of the N functions. I.e., X is no longer 1 x M, but it is instead N x M. Is there a way to parallelize the interpolation in this case (where the x-values of each function to be interpolated are not the same)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, the [`interp`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-interp-function-python/) function would be beneficial to use.

```py
import numpy as np

def f(X, matrix, vector):
    interpolated_values = np.apply_along_axis(np.interp, 0, X, matrix, vector)
    return interpolated_values
```

**Explanation of the above code:**

- `np.apply_along_axis(np.interp, 0, X, matrix, vector)`. This applies the `np.interp` function on each row of the matrix.
- `np.interp`. Interpolates the values of vector at the x-coordinates specified by `X`. Which will help you get the interpolated values for each function in parallel, and that should be much faster than using a loop if *`N` is large.*

***[Code demo](https://trinket.io/python3/7bad554b1c)***

Comment: Thank you so much! Here is one complicating factor: what if X is is not the same vector for each of the N functions? Ie. X is no longer 1XM but is instead NXM? Could np.apply_along_axis() still be used?

Comment: @Random_Astro_Student If` X` is not the same vector for each of the `N` functions, you cannot use `np.apply_along_axis()` directly. In this case, you would need to use a loop to iterate over each function and apply the interpolation separately. But you can still be more efficient if you use `from multiprocessing import Pool`